# What is the real difference between u suffix and unsigned modifier?

Tags: c++

Here I tried using both of them:

```
unsigned short foo1 = 65535;
short foo2 = 65535u;
cout << foo1 << endl << foo2 << endl;
```

And the output was:

```
65535
-1
```

What is the u suffix really used for? And for example if I replace 65535 with 65534 I'd get -2 as an output instead of -1. Meanwhile unsigned does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Well, the `u` suffix changes the type of the integral literal (to `unsinged int`, not `unsigned short`), not the type of the variable initialized with that literal. `foo2` is still of `signed short` type, and is still unable to represent the value `65535`, no matter the form of expression that produces that value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Then what's the point of u suffix?

Comment: To change the type of the integral literal it's appended to. For example, you could use it with a number too large to fit into a `signed int`. Such a need is uncommon, and so these suffixes are only rarely used. In fact, I don't think I've ever seen `u` suffix in a real, non-example code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `1u<<31` is used in real code, because `1<<31` would be undefined for 32bit ints.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just noticed that it's not really usable when declaring variables. Does it work specifically for cout?

Comment: Well, it could be relevant when declaring variables, if you allow the type of the initializer to influence the type of the variable, as in `auto foo2 = 65535u;` (here `foo2` is of type `unsigned int`). I'm not sure I understand the last question. `std::cout << 65535` and `std::cout << 65535u` would produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

In statement `unsigned short foo1 = 65535;`

- `foo1` is an object of type `unsigned short`.
- `65535` is an *integer literal* and its type depends on its value, suffix and the width of integer types, see [the type of the literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal) for full details. Here, the type of `65535` is `int` on a platform where `int` can store value of `65535` with no loss (i.e., where `int` is at least 16-bit wide).

In practice, the integer literal suffix, like `u` in `65535u`, is only required when the decimal integer literal *value* cannot be represented as `long long` without loss (e.g. `18446744073709551615` cannot be represented as signed 64-bit `long long` integer), or, to specify signedness of an integer literal without a cast when passing integer literals to functions. Prior to C++11 `ll` suffix had to be used for literals which don't fit into `long`.

64-bit Linux example where an integer literal doesn't fit into `long long` but does into `unsigned long long`:

```
auto a = 18446744073709551615u; 
auto b = 18446744073709551615; // error: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [-Werror]
```

---

In your code examples, you initialize an object with an integer literal, whatever the integer literal type is, it gets converted to the object type. Then it prints the values of the objects, not of the literals. If you'd like to preserve the original type of the integer literals use `auto` object type, e.g.:

```
auto foo1 = 65535; // decltype(foo1) is int
auto foo2 = 65535u; // decltype(foo2) is unsigned
cout << foo1 << '\n' << foo2 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the u suffix really used for?

What many novice programmers do not realize that in C++ everything pretty much about types. Lets say we have variables:

```
A a; // a type A
B b; // b type B
C c; // c type C
```

and expression:

```
a = b + c;
```

what will happen here? Will it compile? It depends on:

```
1 Is `B + C` valid operation? If not compilation fails, if yes lets call result type as `D`
2 Can `D` be assigned to `A` ? if no, compilation fails.
```

So if that expression would compile or not and more important what operations whould happen depends on all those types. So now if `b` and `c` are variables it is quite clear what types they have, but what if that is a literal `123`? how can we change these types? That's what those suffixes are used for so we can explicitly specify those types if necessary.